# What is the ampere of a piezo material

Tags: voltage, power, current, piezo

The voltage generated by piezo materials varies but does ampere also vary? Are there any sources where I can find this out?

---

I might add that I’m not so much at home in the electrical world but I’m trying ;) I’ve got this piezoelectric component that generates up to a 1000 volts but as I understand it volts alone are not enough for measuring output, you need to multiply it with amperes so hence my question, I hope this clarifies a little.

---

https://www.piceramic.com/en/products/piezoceramic-actuators/patch-transducers/p-876-duraact-patch-transducer-101790/ .. I haven’t an exact requirement as the amount of output will be added to an existing source, the question is more, will the output be enough to be economically interesting.

Comment: I assume you mean "does the *current* vary?".  It's not entirely clear what you're asking -- could you give a concrete example?  A piezoelectric device that's struck lightly will, in general, develop less voltage and current than one struck heavily; a big, robustly-built block of piezo materail will, all things equal, be *capable* of generating more current without breaking.  Clarity of questions leads to clarity of answers.

Comment: Without meaning to be obscure, "volts alone are not enough for measuring output" almost doesn't make sense.  If the piezo in question is a measurement device that you're not trying to extract power from (i.e., it's a microphone or accelerometer, as opposed to the sparker from a cigarette lighter) then you *do* care about it's output impedance (or effective output capacitance), but you *don't* care about it's current capability per se.  Could you tell us *what you're actually trying to do*; that will give your question some grounding in reality.

Comment: Ok, I’m trying to extract power from it, the data sheet that came with it only says the minimum and maximum voltages.

Comment: How much power do you need?  Can you provide a link to the datasheet?

Comment: https://www.piceramic.com/en/products/piezoceramic-actuators/patch-transducers/p-876-duraact-patch-transducer-101790/ .. I haven’t an exact requirement as the amount of output will be added to an existing source, the question is more, will the output be enough to be economically interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Piceramic recommends the [E821](https://www.piceramic.com/en/products/piezo-controllers-drivers/for-energy-harvesting/e-821-electronic-module-for-energy-harvesting-608000/#downloads) module for collecting energy with your piezo patch.

The [datasheet for the E821](https://static.piceramic.com/fileadmin/user_upload/physik_instrumente/files/datasheets/PI_Datasheet_E-821_20150121.pdf) says it provides pulses of 100 millwatts that are 80 milliseconds long.  It has to save up energy over time to get enough energy for each pulse.

Assuming you need 3.3V, then 100 milliwatts means you get 30 milliamperes of current for 80 milliseconds from the converter module.  How often you get those pulses depends on how much your patch is flexed.

That ought to let you know if you can do anything useful with your piezo patch.

Answer (score 0):

A student placed thousands of piezos on a sidewalk and they all had the same polarity. Hundreds of people stomped on them. They charged a capacitor that lit a 10mA LED for a couple of seconds. Almost no current.